# Apex PMD rule for length exceeding certain parameters in methods

Tags: pmd

Is there any custom apex rule already present if the number of lines exceeds a certain parameter in PMD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are multiple apex rules already, see: https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_apex.html . The ones you look for are probably in the category [design](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_apex_design.html). You could use [ExcessiveClassLength](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_apex_design.html#excessiveclasslength) which simply counts the lines. There is also [NcssTypeCount](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_apex_design.html#ncsstypecount), which only counts statements and e.g. ignores comments.

Cross-posting https://sourceforge.net/p/pmd/discussion/188194/thread/c38c328d36/?limit=25